# Migrating 200GB of Postgres data from 9.0 to 9.6

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

We have a simple database with just 5 tables. But 1 table is huge, around 100GB of data by itself, and the indices together are nearly double that size. The server is an old CentOS 5 server with PG 9.0. I'm moving to a more modern setup with SSD hard disks, CentOS 7, and PG 9.6.

Question: what's the best way to migrate data in a simple way. pg_dump it on the old server, move it via rsync or something to the new server and pg_restore? I could do the pg_dump with `-Fc` option, so that we can pg_restore it easily (otherwise it's a text format and we have to use `psql -f` instead). But a trial run suggested that while the pg_dump is OK, the pg_restore on the destination server, which is much faster, goes on and on. We did a `pg_restore --verbose`, but there was no verbosity at all. Perhaps the server was stuck doing IO?

Our `pg.conf` settings for the pg_restore are as follows:

```
maintenance_work_mem = 1500MB 
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
wal_level = minimal
full_page_writes = off
wal_buffers = 64MB
max_wal_senders = 0
wal_keep_segments = 0
archive_mode = off
autovacuum = off
```

What should we do to ensure that the pg_restore works? Right now both servers are offline, so I can do pretty much anything needed -- any settings can be changed.

Some more background info--

Old server: CentOS 5, SCSI RAID 1 disks,  4GB RAM (not much), PG 9.0

New server: CentOS 7 (latest), SSD disk,  16GB RAM,  PG 9.6

Thank you for any pointers on moving large tables in the best way possible. The usual PG documentation doesn't seem to be helping. We've tried both the text dump way and the `-Fc` way.

Comment: You can also pipe `pg_dump (oldmachine) | pg_restore (newmachine)` (additional flags might be needed) , executed from the newmachine's side. This works well if your network is not slower than your disks.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I am doing. But it's a mysterious beast. Pg_dump took 9 hours and created a 200GB file. We moved it over the network in another half day. The new network is quite fast, so using `rclone`, we got it back into the new server in less than an hour. Then we did `pg_restore`, but it said the log is in text format so we need to use `psql -f`. Which we did, and only a very tiny fraction of the database dump (15MB out of 200GB!) has been imported. This is highly frustrating. On the PG documentation website, there's nothing to guide users when this happens. Where should we look?

Comment: First: take a look in the logfiles from your new machine (could be that checkpoints are occuring too frequently) second: I meant `pg_dump| pg_restore` in one piped command, issused from the new side. This would have avoided the intermediate large file. (which you already have now, so you could work from there now)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you `pg_upgrade`:

- Install 9.0.23 on the new server. From source if necessary.
- Set up a streaming replica on the new server using `pg_basebackup` and a suitable `recovery.conf`. Enable WAL archiving and `restore_command` too, in case it becomes desynchronised for any reason.
- Also install 9.6 on the new server
- Do an upgrade test by stopping the replica and attempting a `pg_upgrade` to 9.6. Restart the replica, fix any issues and repeat until you succeed.
- When you're confident `pg_upgrade` will succeed, plan a cut-over time. Stop the 9.0 master and stop the replica. `pg_upgrade` the replica. Start the new 9.6 server.

See the `pg_upgrade` documentation for more info.

Remember: KEEP BACKUPS.

---

If you want simple, just `pg_dumpall` and then pipe to `psql`. But that'll be slow and it'll cause problems if your restore fails partway through then you try to resume, etc.

Better:

If you don't want to use replication, then use parallel-mode `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` with `directory` format input/output if you want to get things done quickly.

- Configure your 9.0 database to accept connections from the 9.6 host and make sure there's a high-performance network connection (gigabit or better).
- Using the 9.6 host, running the 9.6 versions of `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall`:

  - Dump your global objects with `pg_dumpall --globals-only -f globals.sql`
  - Dump your database(s) with `pg_dump -Fd -j4 -d dbname -f dbname.dumpdir` or similar. `-j` is the number of parallel jobs. You'll need to dump each database separately if there are multiple ones.
- Cleanly `initdb` a new PostgreSQL 9.6 install, removing whatever attempts you have previously made (since I don't know what is/isn't there). Alternately, `DROP` any created roles, databases, etc, returning it to a clean state.
- Use `psql` to run the globals script: `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --single-transaction -f globals.sql -d postgres`
- Use `pg_restore` to load the database dumps: `pg_restore --create -d template1 -j4 template1 dbname.dump`, repeating for each dumped DB. You can restore multiple DBs concurrently.

Yes, I know the handling of global objects sucks. And yes, it'd be nice if all this were wrapped up in a simple command. But it isn't. Designs and well thought out patches are welcome if you want to try to improve this. So far nobody's wanted to enough to do the work.

Comment: We have backups. That's not the issue. We also have the live old server until we sort this out to our satisfaction--it's offline and sitting idle, focusing on the maintenance tasks. We would really not want to invest in master/slave replication etc, that's too costly. Isn't PG supposed to be able to this trivial task with just pg_dump and pg_restore? There are less than 10 tables! Just a lot of data in them, none of it binary or anything. Just text. This is disappointing. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated. Most people want to maximise uptime for switchover, but `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` will do the job fine too.

Comment: Thank you Craig. It's very helpful, perhaps for another occasion. For now I'll see what the logs tell me.

Comment: What's the "parallel mode"? Both our servers are offline. That doesn't concern us. But a simple pg_dump and pg_restore is not working. On the destination side pg_restore is pretty stupid as a solution as it tells me first up "ERROR: xyz does not exist" where XYZ are our indexes and one function. Well, obviously it doesn't exist, which is why we're doing the pg_restore! What a knuckleheaded system. Anyway, welcome any thoughts to do a simple copy of the database without replication or parallelism or anything fancy.

Comment: @MoreSpinach Edited with update. Sounds like you're trying a `psql` based restore of a sql-format dump and you're seeing later errors. Look for the *first* error or run with `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`.

Comment: Yes, it's a pg_dump. But when we restore it, it unhelpfully tells us that the format is plain text, so we need to use `psql -f`. So that's what we do. Should we dump in another format? The documentation is so obtuse. This is the simplest possible task: we want to mirror an old database on a new system. Welcome any thoughts.

Comment: @MoreSpinach Use `custom` format (`-Fc`). It's better in every way, and the only reason it's not default is backward-compatibility. As for docs: Documentation comments/recommendations are always welcome, with specifics. What do you expect to see? Once you complete the task, what do you wish had been there and would've helped you? etc. Note that my answer above isn't the *simplest* way, since you're working with a 200GB DB it's the way I'd do it to make it reasonably fast.

Comment: Personally I think we should have a `pg_dumpall` wrapper that knows how to `pg_dump -Fc` each DB, and `pg_restoreall` that knows how to restore all that. But we don't, and nobody's funding work on it or taking their time to develop it. As always, patches are welcome, it's an open source project and that'd be an interesting place for a new contributor to get started. If nobody does the work, it doesn't happen. (I'm busy working on logical replication in postgres).